# Discord.js for deleting all messages that are not bot commands

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a simple Discord bot with node.js, deleting any messages that aren't written by a bot, or are not otherwise that of 3 allowed commands; Think a reverse-whitelist, where only particular phrases are allowed in a channel.

I've been trying to add an OR operator to filter messages, but the only messages it keeps are by the bot, or of the first given string (>fish)-- I can't figure out how to keep the messages using the other 2 commands listed.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.author == client.user)
    return
  if(message.author.bot)
    return
  if(message.content !== ">fish" | message.content !== ">fishinglvl" | message.content !== ">leaderboard fishing")
    return message.delete()
});
```

I also tried `content.valueOf()`, `&&`, and `||` to no avail.
This is my first project in Js, so I know I've definitely messed up somewhere, but I just can't figure out what else to do to fix it.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in the last `if` statement is flawed, you need to use this:

```js
if(![">fish", ">fishinglvl", ">leaderboard fishing"].includes(message.content))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it instantly. Can't thank you enough - I've been driving myself crazy over something so simple all afternoon, lol! Will approve your answer A.S.A.P!